# "net.sf" Java package name for Sourceforge.net projects

Tags: java, package, sourceforge

IIRC Sourceforge Java projects may use the `net.sf` package as their top level package, so my Java project could use `net.sf.mylib` - is this still a valid option? (I have some registered domains but I would prefer to be independent of future naming changes from this side)

Answer (score 1):

You can name a package whatever you want.  It's just custom to name it in reverse domain order (`com.sun.sunlib` for Sun things).

The catch is that you could unintentionally have collisions with other products if they have the same package and class names.